# How can I get the remaining duration of an SCNAction currently in progress?

Tags: swift, scenekit, duration

NodeA has an SCNAction running with a duration of 10 seconds. 
Say 4 seconds have passed.
How can I get the remaining duration (in this case 6 seconds) of the SCNAction in progress?

I plan on using the remaining duration to dynamically create another SCNAction that would add up to 10 seconds.

So NodeA action duration + NodeB action duration = 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the `elapsedTime`, you should use `SCNAction.customAction`, eg:

```
let runningAction = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 10) { (node, elapsedTime) -> () in 
  // do stuff here with elapsedTime
  print(elapsedTime)
}
```

> When the action executes, SceneKit calls the block repeatedly until the action’s duration expires. For each call, SceneKit computes the elapsed time and passes it to the block

documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction/1523692-customaction)

Comment: Exactly the answer to the question.  Marked as answer.